# How to format photos in a JavaScript object that will be passed into a React APP?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image, directory

I'm making a dynamic web page using React that pulls information from a Javascript files that possesses an array of objects with components such as titles, descriptions, and pictures. The problem I'm having is that the location on the page where the picture should go doesn't illustrate the picture, but instead a directory:

> /static/media/ "whatever picture I want's name"

I've included a picture of the page for a better understanding:

[image]

I just want that directory to be replaced with the actual picture I want to be shown. I will now show you the JavaScript file which contains the array of of objects (including the pictures) that I mentioned previously.

```
import Image1 from "./blackmill.jpg"

const myData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text1: "Title",
        text2: "Project 1",
        text3: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
        image1: Image1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text1: "testing",
        text2: "Project 2",
        text3: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
        image1: "Hello"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text1: "brown",
        text2: "Project 3",
        text3: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
        image1: "Hello"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text1: "over",
        text2: "Project 4",
        text3: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
        image1: "Hello"
    }

]

export default myData;
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to React. Thank you!

Edit1: Posting my react code where the images are rendered.

Body.js render function: `render() {

```
    var text2val = this.state.importData.map(item => item.text2)
    var text3val = this.state.importData.map(item => item.text3)
    var link1val = this.state.importData.map(item => item.link1)
    var link2val = this.state.importData.map(item => item.link2)
    var imageval = this.state.importData.map(item=> item.image1)

    return(
        <div className="mainBody">
            <div className="backPain">
                <div className="holder">
                <Column1
                    image={imageval[this.state.currentIndex]} 
                    link1={link1val[this.state.currentIndex]}
                    link2={link2val[this.state.currentIndex]}>
                </Column1>

                <div className="rectHolder">
                    <div className="rectForward" onClick={()=> this.HandleCurrentIndex("inc")}>
                        <h2>Next</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="rectBackward" onClick={()=> this.HandleCurrentIndex("dec")}>
                        <h2>Prev</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Column2 text2={text2val[this.state.currentIndex]} text3={text3val[this.state.currentIndex]}>
                </Column2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

props are then passed down to the Column1.js page:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Column1.css";

function Column1(props) {
    return(
       <React.Fragment>
            <div className="rectImage">
                <h3>{props.image}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="downloadBut1">
                <h2>
                    Source
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div className="downloadBut2">
                <h2>
                    Repository
                </h2>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment> 
    )
}

export default Column1;`
```

Comment: Sometimes picture doesn't state all.

Comment: can you post the bit where you render your images?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: the error is likely to be inside your reactjs page display code - can you post that?

Comment: Yes. I've included both JS pages. Let me explain how they work. The way my page works is it renders the body of the page and the header. Here we are only focussing on the body. It contains the buttons used to change the images and descriptions in addition to the images and descriptions themselves. The information from the JavaScript file filled with the array of objects is passed into the Body and then down into the Column1 file as props. These props include the array of images I created with the var imageval = this.state.importData.map(item=> item.image1) that mapped the images from state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you not just need to replace `<h3>{props.image}</h3>` with `<img src={props.image} />`?

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb right now for not seeing this solution. Thank you!